# Is there documentation for RPi.GPIO

Tags: rpi.gpio

Is there documentation for `RPi.GPIO`? I have searched the web and can't find anything.

I know I can use `pydoc` or `help()` but this produces the following:-

```
wait_for_edge(...)
    Wait for an edge.  Returns the channel number or None on timeout.
    channel      - either board pin number or BCM number depending on which mode is set.
    edge         - RISING, FALLING or BOTH
    [bouncetime] - time allowed between calls to allow for switchbounce
    [timeout]    - timeout in ms
```

This is OK, in as far as it goes, but doesn't really explain.
I assume the function blocks until the interrupt, but this is not stated.
What are the limits/defaults for timeout?

I have the following code, which I start on boot. Pressing the button successfully shuts down, but I have noticed it also seems to shut down at other times.

I could add some code to verify the button push, or some circuitry to make it more robust, but though I would check the documentation first.

```python
while True:
    # set an interrupt on a falling edge and wait for it to happen
    GPIO.wait_for_edge(INT, GPIO.FALLING)

    subprocess.call(['poweroff'], shell=True, \
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Edit 2016-01-03

---

I downloaded the source from SourceForge, which made things somewhat clearer, but the `timeout` parameter seems to be missing in action.

Comment: Have you tried here: http://raspi.tv/2013/rpi-gpio-basics-7-rpi-gpio-cheat-sheet-and-pointers-to-rpi-gpio-advanced-tutorials

Comment: it's common knowledge that you can always find the documentation on the source code and examples. Authors use seldescripted names: usually 'wait' means that :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The official documentation is http://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Examples/

It doesn't seem to have a traditional API style of documentation.

Comment: This answers my question - with "No". I have tried teaching myself `python` many times over the last 2 years. I like the philosophy and the language itself (apart from classes - which are bizarre). When I want to develop something using a library I get lost in the woeful documentation, and take the easy path and use `c` or `c++`, with well documented libraries.

Comment: I can grasp a language tg

Comment: @Milliways My [pigpio Python](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html) module has, perhaps, more traditional documentation.  Python classes are pretty much the same (in my opinion) with the Arduino class wrappers for motors/servos etc., i.e. pretty similar to C++ classes.

Answer (score 3):

I have finally found a Python library with **documentation** [gpiozero](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

I recommend this to anyone attempting to manipulate **GPIO** with Python.

Just to clarify I also highly recommend the [pigpio Python module](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html) which has more functionality.

Comment: This is not an answer to the posted question. gpiozero is a completely different software library

Comment: @user3728501 gpiozero is actually a wrapper for RPi.GPIO (although it can use other pin factories)

Comment: Point still stands. It's not the same thing, and doesn't have the same use cases. OP specifically stated asking for documentation for RPI.GPIO, not gpiozero, which is completely different.

Comment: @user3728501 You seem to have failed to notice that I was the author of the original Question (more than 5 years ago). My additional Answer (while not detracting from the Answer I accepted) is intended to help any new uses who may read this. Even though I have since written an enhanced version of RPI.GPIO I still recommend gpiozero to any new users. It has exactly the same functionality - just better documented and easier to use.

Comment: So you answered your own question with an answer which wasn't relevant to the question?

Comment: It would seem the original "desire" was to get a GPIO library with documentation since the OP "finally found" something, only the OP can comment on that. Since gpiozero wraps RPi.GPIO, I would debate that it is a "completely different software library". Consider that readers finding this question would likely find this answer, given by the OP, to be valuable.